# Implementing action bar sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, actionbarsherlock-map

I have implemented the actionbarsherlock in my project. I am in need to run/use this project in another machine for developing. how can i do this.

Comment: will you please be more specific on your problem ?

Comment: while implementing this it shows error in R.R cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: i have implemented abs in my project and it is working fine. when i am using this project in another machine for developing it is not able to configure the abs.The R cannot be generated.Is there any way to configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can try [this](https://bitbucket.org/) site for code hosting with a `GIT` repository. This way you will be able to access your code from any computer with a internet connection.

Comment: Hi Thank U.Now it is working fine.